# How to install authrootstl.cab offline?

Tags: windows-7, certificate, code-signing

When I try to install the [authrootstl.cab](http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab) offline it won't work.
The certificates are installed but Windows doesn't trust the file, and will continue to try to download it. It says the list signing certificate is invalid.

I discovered the offline installation requires both [MicCerTruLisPCA_2009-04-02.crl](http://www.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/MicCerTruLisPCA_2009-04-02.crl) and [microsoftrootcert.crl](http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl). But installing those doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: AFAIK, installing the certificates should not require the CRL files - the CRL files are simply updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way of installing it. But I could disable the CRL checking in Internet Explorer settings.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with the list of root certificates on your computer.

Download and install first Microsoft's [Update for Root Certificates](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=25249786-2b8e-4c51-8f4b-727ce25cc2c5).